# XML tree traversal using tail recursion in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, recursion, functional-programming, tail

Let us say we have an XML like

```
<a id="one">
 <aa id="one -depth one"> 
    <aaa id="one -depth two">
    </aaa>
 </aa>
 <bb id="two -depth one"> 
    <bbb id="two -depth two">
       <bbbb id="bbbb depth three">
       </bbbb>
    </bbb>
 </bb>

</a>
<b id="two"></b>
<c id="three"></c>
<d id="four"></d>
<e id="five"></e>'
```

Then, I want to have an output similar to the following by using Scala's tail recursion or any other way while considering performance and code quality as well. The depth of nodes can be dynamic (not fixed, and could go to any depth)

```
List(
Object(A, List(
       Object(AA, List(
                     Object(AAA, List())
                       )
              ),
       Object(BB, List(
                     Object(BBB, List(
                                    Object(BBBB, List())
                            )        )
                       )
              )
           )
   ),
Object(B, List()),
Object(C, List()),
Object(D, List()),
Object(E, List())
)
```

Any suggestion or even some kind of pseudo code would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does your data come from? Do you just want to construct some arbitrary structure from code? Did you take a look at [scala.xml](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0-M3/index.html#scala.xml.Elem)?

Comment: Was using those libraries as well. But struggling abit with handling/processing dynamic depth bits of XML. Hmmm...

Comment: Hi nietaki, is there any way to set headers for XML load of some URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question here with a Scala's PSEUDO code. It would be cool if a better alternative is contributed.

```
def walkXmlPath(someXMLNodes: Node) = {
   // Check if a node has a child/children nodes

   // If there are children nodes, then iterate over them

   // Inside the iteration, do some necessary operations and call 'def walkXmlPath(...)' until the complete tree walk 

   // Return some processed nodes' extracts
}
```